# Merge a Python Array Along an Axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, append

I've been trying to populate a training data set for use in a Keras model. Using numpy's `append` function everything *works* fine, but it is **incredibly slow**. Here's what I'm doing right now:

```py
def populateData():
    images = np.zeros([1, 4, 512, 512, 6])
    for m in range(2):
        for n in range(4):
            batch_np = np.zeros([4, 512, 512, 6])

            # Doing stuff with the batch...
            # ...

            images = np.append(images, batch_np, axis=0)
```

As the size of the array grows with each pass, the amount of time numpy takes to append new data increases pretty much exponentially. So, for instance, the first pass takes around ~1 second, the third takes just over ~3 seconds. By the time I've done a dozen or more, each `append` operation takes many *minutes*(!). Based on the current pace of things, it could take days to complete.

[image: Line graph showing the time (seconds) per iteration (#) when using numpy.append. Values increase exponentially.]

I'd like to be able to get my training data set populated sometime before the next ice age. Beyond "getting better hardware", **what can I do to speed up `np.append(...)`**? My understanding is that Numpy's `append` function copies the entire array each time this function gets called. Is there an equivalent function that does *not* perform a copy each time? Or that uses a reference value instead, and just modifies that?

I've attempted to rewrite some of this using Python's built-in `list append` function, but it doesn't provide `axis` support like numpy's append function. So, while that appears to be *much much* faster, it doesn't quite work for this multi-dimensional setup.

---

**TL;DR: Is there a way to specify an axis when appending to a Python list? If not, is there a more optimal way to append to a N-D array along a specified axis / speed up `numpy.append`?**

Comment: Don't append, create an empty array with the correct size from the start and populate the correct slice with each iteration.

Comment: LIst append, with one join (with `np.array`, `np.concatenate` or `np.stack`) at the end is faster than any sort of repeated array concatenate (with copies a lot as you found).

Comment: Once you have a list of lists, or list of arrays, you can specify an `axis` when converting that to an array with `np.stack`.  If you use `np.array(alist)` you will join them on an new first axis.  Read the function documentation, and then experiment with some small arrays - ones where you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.stack` and use a python list:

```
images = []
for m in range(2):
    for n in range(4):
        batch_np = np.zeros([4, 512, 512, 6])
        ...
        images.append(batch_np)
images = np.stack(images, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> images.shape
(8, 4, 512, 512, 6)
```

Or allocate the whole array before loops:

```
M = 2
N = 4
images = np.zeros([M*N, N, 512, 512, 6])
for i, m in enumerate(range(M)):
    for j, n in enumerate(range(N)):
        batch_np = np.zeros([N, 512, 512, 6])
        images[i+j] = batch_np
```

Output:

```
>>> images.shape
(8, 4, 512, 512, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to specify an axis with the list append?  These two loops produce the same shape:

```
In [62]: arr = np.zeros([0,3,4])
    ...: for i in range(5):
    ...:     arr = np.append(arr, np.ones((1,3,4)), axis=0)
    ...: arr.shape
Out[62]: (5, 3, 4)

In [63]: alist = []
    ...: for i in range(5):
    ...:     alist.append(np.ones((3,4)))
    ...: arr = np.array(alist)    
In [64]: arr.shape
Out[64]: (5, 3, 4)
```

`stack` with the default axis 0 does the same thing:

```
In [65]: np.stack(alist, axis=0).shape
Out[65]: (5, 3, 4)
In [66]: np.stack(alist, axis=1).shape
Out[66]: (3, 5, 4)
```